# What is the name of this red flower? And how do I care for it?

Tags: identification, succulents

Does anyone have any idea what plant this is?

I got it but it was missing its tag. I looked it up and thought it resembled a flower called Kalanchoe, but of course I cannot be certain at all.

Can I have a second opinion?

[image: Visual reference]

Comment: Did someone spray the leaves with glitter?!

Comment: I believe so, came from the store that way, so I am guessing the store thought it was a good idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's *Kalanchoe blossfeldiana*. It's a succulent native to Madagascar. They are pretty undemanding houseplants, but need good light and mustn't be over-watered: allow the soil to dry fully between watering and do not leave it sitting in water.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually what I found, but I wasn't sure to begin with.

Comment: PS @Tich, here is how you properly pronounce Kalanchoe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr_1-g9eaAs Please wipe off the "glitter" from the leaves using warm water. It will help your specimen.